# What would cause a form validator with the right naming convention not to execute?

Tags: forms, media, files

I am supporting a site that uses version 7.x-2.0-alpha of the [File Entity module](http://drupal.org/project/file_entity), and a user reported that updating files was not working.

Using a debugger and comparing to another site, I tracked this down to the fact that the `file_entity_edit_validate()` function was not executing, which contains the code for actually saving the file that is in the "replace_upload" attribute of the form. The validator is not named specifically in the form definition; it looks designed to just be called by naming convention.

When I manually add `'#validate' => array('file_entity_edit_validate')` to the submit handler array for the form, everything works as expected.

This seems to be a conflict coming from some other module on the site, as when I install it from scratch using the same codebase, this problem does not occur. Also, building a site from scratch using the same versions of Media and File Entity does not exhibit the problem.

There are a ton of other modules running on the site. What could I look for that would be causing that validate hook not to fire?

Comment: It could be a broken hook_form_alter replacing the validate handler with another one and not preserving the existing handlers, e.g `$form['#validate'] = array('some_validate_handler');` instead of `$form['#validate'][] = 'some_validate_handler';`

Comment: @DavidThomas, thanks for the idea. I disabled the manualcrop and file_admin modules that were executing hook_form_alter functions on the file_entity_edit form, but that didn't help. The only ones left now are being provided by path, media, or the file_entity module itself.